# @UiHandler : Required to delegate handlers?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a class which extends the GXT ComboBox :

```
public class RemoteCombo<Row> extends ComboBox<Row> {
    ...
}
```

Later, I use it in some code :

```
@UiField(provided = true)
RemoteCombo<Town> town;

@UiHandler("town")
public void onTownValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent<Town> event) {
  ...
}
```

I get the following error :

```
[ERROR] Field 'town' does not have an 'addValueChangeHandler' method associated.
```

This is false because `town` is a `RemoteCombo`, `RemoteCombo` extends `ComboBox`, `ComboBox` has this method.

If I delegate this method in **RemoteCombo.java**, it works :

```
public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<Row> handler){
  return super.addValueChangeHandler(handler);
}
```

Nevertheless, I find weird that I have to delegate every method that I need to use with `@UiHandler`. Do I do something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: 1. Double-check the provided RemoteCombo is using the proper implementation (the one extending ComboBox). 2. Does catching ChangeEvent instead of ValueChangeEvent<T> works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are doing right.

Take a look at what Colin Alworth wrote (at the end of the thread).

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?240102-How-do-I-add-a-selection-listener-to-a-SimpleComboBox&langid=4

and here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6091